# R: calculating the change in a value from one observation to the next within a data frame with cases and observations

Tags: r, dataframe

Hello I'm new to R and am having trouble completing what should be a fairly simple task. I'm sure there is a straightforward solution, but I couldn't find it online (including on StackOverflow)

I have a dataframe with `Cases`, and `Observations` and a variable `Amount`. `Cases` are factors, `observations` are integers, and together they form an indices that so that the row containing `Case` = 3 and `Observation` = 4 corresponds to the 4th observation of the 3rd Case, and the row containing `Case` = 4 and `Observation` = 1 corresponds to the first observation of the 4th case.

I am trying to write a script that calculates the change in Amount from one observation within each case to the next observation within the same case, and then stores that difference in a new column in the dataframe at the row associated with the first these two observation. So when I am done the new column will contain the change in the amount from the current rows observation to the next observation within the same case.

the dataframe is of the form :

```
case <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4)
obs <- c(rep(1,6),rep(2,6),rep(3,4))
amount <- c(0,2,12,1,0,20,1,2,22,2,1,50,5,2,100,28)
d.example <- data.frame(case,obs,amount)
d.example$case <- as.factor(d.example$case)
```

> ```
> case obs Amount 
> 1    1   0
> 2    1   2 
> 3    1   12
> 4    1   1
> 5    1   0 
> 6    1   20
> 1    2   1
> 2    2   2
> 3    2   22
> 4    2   2
> 5    2   1
> 6    2   50
> 1    3   5
> 2    3   2
> 3    3   100
> 4    3   28
> ```

Note: the data is not balanced each case can have a different number of observations

The result should be ( for now I am placing `-1` in for NA)

> ```
> case obs Amount deltaAmount
> 1    1   0      1
> 2    1   2      0
> 3    1   12     10
> 4    1   1      1
> 5    1   0      1
> 6    1   20     30
> 1    2   1      4
> 2    2   2      0
> 3    2   22     78
> 4    2   2      26
> 5    2   1      -1
> 6    2   50     -1
> 1    3   5      -1
> 2    3   2      -1
> 3    3   100    -1
> 4    3   28     -1
> ```

I've been attempting to do this using a nested for loops

```
deltaAmount <- NULL
deltaAmount <- rep(-1, length(d$Case))
d$deltaAmount <- deltaAmount

x <- NULL
y <- NULL


for( i in unique(d$Case)) {   # i is the case index
    x <- NULL
# set x equal to a vector containing all the observations for the ith case except the first observation 
    x <- subset( unique(d$Observation[which(d$Case == i)]), unique( d$Observation[which(d$Case == i)]) > 1)

    for( j in x ) { # j is the observation index (starts at 2 to avoid the error that would occur if we subtract a preceeding obsevation from the first observation)

        d$AmountRaised[which(d$Case == i) & which(d$Observation == j)] - d$AmountRaised[which(d$Case == i) & which(d$Observation == j-1)] -> y
        y -> d$deltaAmount[which( d$Case == i & d$Observation == j-1 )] 

    }
}
```

When I run this the command take a very long time to run. Almost as if it is stuck in an infinite loop ( I have yet to run this to its completion) when I terminate the program R states that I have more than 50 warning messages. They are all of the form

`1: In which(d$Case == i) & which(d$Observation == j) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length`

However the additional column is created and several values have been changed from `-1` to `0`.

My data frame is large (770000 rows).

Once I get this to work I will need to do the same thing except with dates using difftime(). I realize I am probably going about this the wrong way (ie there is probably a better way to do this without using nested for loops), but please keep in mind that I need to take the difference between sets of dates, if you suggest a different approach.

Sorry for asking such a long question, I hope I made everything clear.

Thankyou in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming data is sorted by `obs` (easy enough to do), here is an implementation in base R:

```
d.example$case.delta <- 
  with(d.example, ave(amount, case, FUN=function(x) c(diff(x), NA)))
```

The `ave` function breaks up `amount` vector by `case`, and then for each of the groups uses the `diff` function (slightly modified as you can see).  This produces (ordered by case for clarity):

```
with(d.example, d.example[order(case, obs), ])
#    case obs amount case.delta
# 1     1   1      0          1
# 7     1   2      1          4
# 13    1   3      5         NA
# 2     2   1      2          0
# 8     2   2      2          0
# 14    2   3      2         NA
# 3     3   1     12         10
# 9     3   2     22         78
# 15    3   3    100         NA
# 4     4   1      1          1
# 10    4   2      2         26
# 16    4   3     28         NA
# 5     5   1      0          1
# 11    5   2      1         NA
# 6     6   1     20         30
# 12    6   2     50         NA
```

Comment: Do you have any suggestions as to how this could be adapted for use with timediff(). Right now I am using `d.test$Time.Delta <- with(d.test, ave(d.test$CurrentDate, d.test$Case, FUN=function(x) c(difftime(x, units = "days"), NA )))`

Comment: @user6179, you will need to do something like `c(difftime(head(x, -1L), tail(x, (-1L))), NA)`

Comment: I tried `d$Delta.T <- with(d, ave(d$CurrentDate, d$Case, FUN=function(x) c(difftime(head(x, -1L), tail(x, (-1L))), NA )))` but that didn't seem to work, specifically the command didn't terminate.

Comment: @user6179, why don't you update your post with a `dput` of a small meaningful portion of your data.  Hard to debug without it.

Comment: This is the output I got from dput: let me know if this is in the wrong format:

Comment: list(Case = c(33L, 55L, 305L, 33L, 55L, 305L, 33L, 33L, 305L), 
    Observation = c(1L, 1L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 12L, 13L, 20L, 32L), 
    CurrentDate = c(33L, 55L, 12751L, 19770L, 19792L, 38895L, 
    44145L, 94572L, 227750L), AmountRaised = c(835L, 1320L, 280L, 
    1235L, 3648L, 1430L, 1410L, 1610L, 3080L), Currency = c(6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), TargetReached = c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Delta.A = c(335L, 2318L, 1150L, 
    175L, 647L, 1650L, 200L, 35L, NA))

Comment: @user6179, these do not appear to have times?  Also, it's a list, not a data frame.  Finally, you should edit your question and put the `dput` there.

Answer (score 3):

This is just the situation that plyr (and dplyr) are built for - split/apply/combine. You can use `diff()` to get the differences between rows. As pointed out in the comments, `diff()` is dependent on order, so this will only work if the ordering is appropriate:

With dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
d.example %.%
  group_by(case) %.%
  mutate(deltaAmount = c(diff(amount), NA))

#    case obs amount deltaAmount
# 1     1   1      0           1
# 2     2   1      2           0
# 3     3   1     12          10
# 4     4   1      1           1
# 5     5   1      0           1
# 6     6   1     20          30
# 7     1   2      1           4
# 8     2   2      2           0
# 9     3   2     22          78
# 10    4   2      2          26
# 11    5   2      1          NA
# 12    6   2     50          NA
# 13    1   3      5          NA
# 14    2   3      2          NA
# 15    3   3    100          NA
# 16    4   3     28          NA
```

and with plyr:

```
library(plyr)
d.out <- ddply(d.example, .(case), mutate, 
               deltaAmount = c(diff(amount), NA))
d.out
#    case obs amount deltaAmount
# 1     1   1      0           1
# 2     1   2      1           4
# 3     1   3      5          NA
# 4     2   1      2           0
# 5     2   2      2           0
# 6     2   3      2          NA
# 7     3   1     12          10
# 8     3   2     22          78
# 9     3   3    100          NA
# 10    4   1      1           1
# 11    4   2      2          26
# 12    4   3     28          NA
# 13    5   1      0           1
# 14    5   2      1          NA
# 15    6   1     20          30
# 16    6   2     50          NA
```

Comment: using plyr I was able to get this to work on this example, but not on my actual data frame. after ordering the actual data frame by observations I try this on my actual data frame, but the command doesn't terminate, it behaves as if it was stuck in an infinite loop. Using subset I reduced the my actual data frame to one with 9277 rows of 20 variables, so I would expect this to run at the most in the tens of minutes. Would these having extra columns some how complicate things?

Comment: plyr is not really fast with big datasets - give dplyr a go. How about the other solution?

Comment: I've gotten the other solution to work, with Amount. I am currently trying to adapt it so it will work with difftime(). But, I'll try dplyr as well, Thanks for the help.